# R: Change a variable from int to chr for one variable in a dataframe

Tags: r

Very new to R but this should be so simple and it's been vexing me for over a week.
I have a csv I read into R and it looks like this:

```
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID  : int  1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008
 $ Name: chr  "Joe" "Mary" "Paul" "Peter" ...
 $ Job : chr  "Driver" "Surveyor" "Senior Surveyor" "Cleaner" ...
```

I want ID to be a chr (these are employee IDs, I don't want R to calculate quartiles and all sorts of other things when I run summary(), they're just labels). But whatever I try, I only get a printout of the numbers as characters, but when I run str(mydata), it's integer again. For example:

```
> as(mydata$ID, "character")
[1] "1000" "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" "1005" "1006" "1007" "1008"
> class(mydata$ID)
[1] "integer"
```

Is there a simple way to turn mydata$ID into char and force the employee IDs to be labels? There are loads of answers to the opposite but I've been trying to find an answer to this for over a week now and I couldn't. Thank you very much.

Comment: `mydata$ID <- as.character(mydata$ID)`

Comment: (Typically, you won't need the generic `as()` function unless you're dealing with S4 classes or something.) Broadly speaking, the lesson here is that in R you always have to assign an action somewhere for the result to persist. R doesn't keep "side effects".

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, it has worked! Appreciate it, joran. :-)

Comment: And thanks for that additional explanation, too. I now realise that I thought you could only do x <-  if x did not exist yet, i.e. creating a new one. I did  not realise that mydata$ID <- was a possibility at all! Thanks again.

Comment: It's not just a possibility. It's a necessity.